# Using Firebase inside a iOS framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have a framework in which i'm trying to use Firebase/MLKit for OCR.
So firebase is linked to the framework and to the main app which is using this framework also.

As a result i'm getting messages like this:

> Class GMVx_PHTPhenotypeSSOAccountService is implemented in both.... 
>   One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Is there any way to set this up correctly?
I coudn't find working solution anywhere.

Comment: How did you integrated Firebase to the app, to the framework and how the framework integrated to the app?
Best way will be to integrate Firebase via Cocoapods to both.

Comment: I integrated by adding framework files manually. I also tried with Cocoapods, but got the same result.